# How to provide xcodebuild with provisioning profiles for your app and extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, provisioning

Good day,

We just added an extension to our iOS app and we're trying to build it on the command line with limited success. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to tell the command line to set a different provisioning profile for each target in the scheme.

Building in Xcode using manual or automatic works. I even built the app/extension with the manual setting in Xcode using the command line with just the following and the app built. I was trying to determine if the manual command line build would show how it's setting its variables, but it doesn't:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Project`

The end result of this is that we need to get the build into Azure Pipelines, but without understanding how to get it to build on the command line, we can't start putting it into Pipelines.

This is the command line we're using (so far):

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Project -allowProvisioningUpdates CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: My Company” PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=“Provisioning profile name”`

Now, of course, we only set one profile because Apple's docs doesn't show how to set a different profile for a specific target.

This is the result:

`error: Provisioning profile "My Provisioing Profile" has app ID "com.company.project", which does not match the bundle ID "com.company.project.shortcuts". (in target 'ProjectShortcuts' from project 'Project')`

I've read some solutions using variables in Xcode, but that's not viable for us. Is there some way to tell `xcodebuild` to use profile A for target A and profile B for target B?